# gridview merged row needs separate links from different values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c# ASP.NET
I have a GridView similar to below

```
ID | Name | Date       | DocID
-----------------------------
 1 | John | 27/02/2019 |  1
 2 | Mary | 20/01/2019 |  2
 3 | Mark | 01/01/2019 |  3
 3 | Mark | 01/01/2019 |  4
 3 | Mark | 01/01/2019 |  5
```

The DocID is a link that goes to the document uploaded to the database.

I have been able to merge the the duplicate rows into 1 so my table currently looks like below

```
ID | Name | Date       | DocID
-----------------------------
 1 | John | 27/02/2019 |  1
 2 | Mary | 20/01/2019 |  2
 3 | Mark | 01/01/2019 |  3 4 5
```

Which is fine apart from that I now have 1 link for all 3 documents instead of a link for each document.

Is there a way I can have each of the documents have its own link but only use the one LinkButton or is there something i'm missing and a link button isn't the way to do this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here is some of my code for context
**Create GridView**

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblQuote.qID, tblQuote.qInsurer, tblQuote.qDate, tblQuote.qQuote, tblQuote.qTerms, tblQuote.qUser, tblQMethod.qmDesc, " +
                                                "STUFF((SELECT ' ' + CAST(dID AS VARCHAR) FROM tblDocuments WHERE tblDocuments.qID = tblQuote.qID FOR XML PATH('')),1, 0, '') [dID], " +
                                                "STUFF((SELECT ' ' + dName FROM tblDocuments WHERE tblDocuments.qID = tblQuote.qID FOR XML PATH('')),1, 0, '') [dName] " +
                                                "FROM tblQuote INNER JOIN tblQMethod ON tblQuote.qQMethod = tblQMethod.qmID " +
                                                "WHERE tblQuote.rID = " + Session["riskID"], tcf))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                gvQuote.DataSource = dt;
                gvQuote.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

**Document Link**

```
protected void lnkDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dID = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        byte[] bytes;
        string fileName, contentType;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblDocuments WHERE dID = @dID", tcf))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dID", dID);
            tcf.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["dDocument"];
                contentType = sdr["dType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["dName"].ToString();
            }
            tcf.Close();
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

**GridView TemplateField**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents Link">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDocument" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dID") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("dName") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("dID") %>' OnClick="lnkDocument_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Repeater Code**
by adding this code below under RowDataBound I have been able to get the links to appear separately but now all the documents are showing in the DocID

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Repeater rp = (Repeater)e.Row.FindControl("rpDocument");
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dID, dName FROM tblDocuments", tcf))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    rp.DataSource = dt;
                    rp.DataBind();
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the markup generated in your gridview column template.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Literal ID="ltMarkup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocID") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then manage your links generating in your gridview's rowdatabound event:

```
 protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      string[] docs = e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Split(' ');

      var lt = (Literal)e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("ltMarkup");
      foreach(var d in docs)
          lt.Text +=  String.Format("<a href='{0}'>Link {0}</a><br/>", d);
    }
 }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks I've tried this but it is still showing the 1 link, I've added the code I have to hopefully show a bit of context.

Comment: Should work fine. Did you adapt it to your usage? I only used `e.Row.Cells[3]` and `e.Row.Cells[3].Text` as examples but you may need swap these with appropriate values (I can't tell without seeing more code)

Comment: yes, my cell i am using is 7 so i have changed the 3 to a 7. I have added in the Literal and refer to the correct control ID. I am however seeing the word Link in all the cells in the doc column but i only need the link to show in the cells that have a document to download. If i remove the word Link from the code i don't see any links but i do still see the Doc ID's

Comment: again, its hard to tell without the code but you may be able to do this with separate columns, one for the data and one for the display of links. assign `string[] docs` from cell[7] (data only) and modify your literal in cell[8] (display template)

Comment: I've been able to add a repeater into the RowDataBound (code added above) which works to separate the links but it is now showing in all rows instead of the rows relevant.